# copy file from one directory from one folder to another using sas

Tags: windows, sas

I matrying to copy the files which is coming to the main folder to another with out the date st. using the attached code to achive it . but getting tthe error message the System cannot find file specified.

```
%let rptpath = R:\CDW Reporting\Ad-Hoc\WR#_JAS0031 -Walls Regional HospitalHainey\Data Out\;

%let rptname = Walls Regional Hospital Hainey Report;
%let rptdate = today();
%let rptdatefmt = YYMMDDd10.;
data _NULL_;
cmd = "COPY &rptpath.&rptname" ||put(&rptdate,&rptdatefmt) || ".xlsx   C:\Users\UCS1MKP\Desktop\y\&rptname..xlsx";
call system(cmd);
run; `
```

now how to overcome this.Thanks in advance.Manesh

Answer (score 0):

Since your paths include spaces you need to add quotes around them in the generated COPY command.

```
cmd = "COPY ""&rptpath.&rptname" 
  || put(&rptdate,&rptdatefmt)
  || ".xlsx""  ""C:\Users\UCS1MKP\Desktop\y\&rptname..xlsx"" "
;
```

Comment: Still its not woking . Is there any other method like X statements? @Tom

Comment: I like to use FILENAME with PIPE option. Then you can read the error messages from the operating system. Replace the CALL SYSTEM command with these statements instead in your DATA _NULL_  `infile cmd pipe filevar=cmd; input; put _infile_;`